# ShopifyBuy js API returning 404 for single product

Tags: shopify

I am trying to debug a 404 issue for a product using the ShopifyBuy client api. The product is always returning 404 and I am unable to understand why.

The code below is where the issue is happening. The variable productId has a valid id for an active product in the Shopify store but client.fetchProduct returns 404. I suspect this is an issue in Shopify but getting help from support is taking forever.

```
var productId = productDiv.data("shopify-id");
client.fetchProduct(productId).then(function (fetchedProduct) {
   productDiv.data("product", fetchedProduct);
});
```

Request URL: [https://shop.mysite.co/api/apps/6/product_listings/[productId]](https://shop.mysite.co/api/apps/6/product_listings/%5BproductId%5D)

Has anyone seen this issue before to point me to the right direction here?

Thanks

Comment: What is the Request URL? it doesn't seem valid API endpoint in Shopify?

Comment: hey @Onkar thanks for getting back to me. The actual request url returning 404 https://shop.babease.co/api/apps/6/product_listings/1246192566308.